# is it a bad idea to put testing environment and jira as subdomain to the main website domain?

Tags: web, dns, webserver, subdomain

Say I have a website `http://mydomain.com`. I'm setting up Jira and testing environment which are on the different server and IP address than the main website. Is it a bad idea to set them up as subdomains: `testenv.mydomain.com` and `jira.mydomain.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this setting on many occasions and use it myself. I do not consider it a bad idea, on the contrary.